# Context is null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm newbie to flutter. I've created a `StatefulWidget` with `initState()` declared, inside it there's a `_firebaseMessaging.configure()` function which calls a `showDialog()`. At first run, it's works fine, but after change page several times, everytime there's a push notification which means functions inside `_firebaseMessaging.configure()` is called again. At that moment, I found that context is null when `showDialog()` was called. What could be wrong?

Here's my code:

```
showDialog<bool>(
        context: context, // this one sometimes null?
        builder: (_) => _buildDialog(context, title, body),
      ).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
        ...
```

Comment: on initState() context is null because our widgets are built after onBuild() method. You need to move such codes to build method instead of initState()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to avoid reconfigured again 
official example work well because it has only page will not have reconfigured issue 
That why first time work well and after change some page it cause reconfigured issue 
one of the method from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32698#issuecomment-525370455 
use a `bool` to check if it configured already

```
bool _isConfigured = false;

...

if (!_isConfigured) {
  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: '+message.toString());
      return;
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: '+message.toString());
      return;
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: '+message.toString());
      return;
    },
  );
  _isConfigured = true;
}
```